$S^{n}(V)$ is "approximately" $V$ when $n$ goes to infinity (in the setting of normed space)
Let $B$ be a (separable) Banach space. $(v_{i})_{i}, i\in\mathbb{N}$ being a family of linear independent vectors. $V$ being the span of $v_{i}$. I try to prove that $V$ is dense in $B$. I define a continuous linear and surjective mapping $S: B\rightarrow B$. I was able to show that:

$S^{n}(V)$ is dense for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
$S^{n+1}(v_{n})=v_{n}$.

So I am thinking, if we let $n$ goes to infinity, $S^{n!}(V)$ somehow "goes to V", we “intuitively” get back our original set $V$, and it will be dense because of (1). However, I don’t know how to formalize this concept, I don’t know if it can be done as well. If someone can provide a way to do this, or telling me that more properties are needed to do that, I will be grateful.
Edit:
I feel like I should add more properties. $B$ is actually a Hilbert space (a real sequence space with some weighted inner product). $S$ is the left shift operator in $B$. Under this setting, the operator norm of $S$ is greater than 1.

It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Which parts of this are hypotheses, and which parts are you trying to prove?  For example, without more information, it is impossible to prove that $V$ is dense in $B$, because it might not be.

@LSpice I think the OP is trying to ask if conditions 1 and 2 are enough to imply $V$ is dense in $B$.

@DavidGao, re, thanks.  That question makes sense, but I am still confused (for example, what is the importance of setting $N = n!$, and then never using $N$ (except in the edit, where it is not clear if $n$ and $N$ are meant to be different)?), so I hope that the asker will clarify.

The part I am trying to prove is $V$ is dense in $B$. It is given that $S^{n}(V)$ is dense for all $n$, and $S^{n+1}(v_{n})=v_{n}$.

@Ken.Wong I believe LSpice was trying to ask what the significance of $N = n!$ is. I suppose the point is $S^{n+1}(v_n) = v_n$ implies $S^{n!}(v_i) = v_i$ for all $i < n$?

@DavidGao yes, this is the point of it.

At least this is true when $S$ is known to be contractive, since then the second condition implies $S^n$ is isometric on $V$ for all $n$, so $S$ is isometric on $S(V)$, which is dense, whence $S$ is an isometric isomorphism and the result easily follows.

unfortunately, the norm of $S$ is greater than 1.

If you have a particular weighted $\ell^2$-space in mind, why not specify it? and then it will be easier for people to help you decide if $V$ is dense
